# Spring MVC with RESTful implementation and simple Spring MVC, how to differentiate between them?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, restful-architecture

The point is, how exactly to identify a Spring MVC implementing RESTful web services? Assuming use of Spring 3.x, use of which all annotations in the project will indicate that the project implements RESTful web services?

Answer (score 2):

If the controller is annotated with `@RestController` or the `@RequestMapping` methods has `@ResponseBody` on return type then those are REST Service.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming you are using Spring 3.x**

All the Spring MVC components has to use the common `@Controller` annotation to mark that as the **controller servlet**.
In short controller servlet should be annotated with @Controller

When you implement a `RESTful web services` in Spring 3.x, the response would be always sent with the response body.
In short Controllers which implement a REST API should be annotated with `@Controller`+`@ResponseBody`

### Additional information

**Spring 4.0** has provided a specialized version of controller- `@RestController`.

`@RestController` is a stereotype annotation that **combines** `@ResponseBody` and `@Controller`. `@RestController` annotation itself annotated with `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`.

```
 @Target(value=TYPE)
 @Retention(value=RUNTIME)
 @Documented
 @Controller
 @ResponseBody
public @interface RestController
```

[See the Spring docs for more information](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html)